# code failing with $ not defined: Uncaught reference error and Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

Below is my html page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Networked  Graph</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="{{url_for('static',filename='graphlogic.js')}}</script>
</head>
<body>
  <style>
    . links line {
      stroke: #999;
      stroke-opacity: 0.6;
    }
    .nodes circle {
      stroke: #fff;
      stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }
    .nodes circle {
      stroke: #fff;
      stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }
 </style>
 <svg id="Network_graph" width="960" height="600"></svg>
 <script type="text/javascript">
   var IDData = JSON.stringify({{data|safe}});
 </script>
 <div id="graph"></div>
```

in developer mode my var IDData looks as follows:
it is an array of array where the length is not fixed but the positioning of elements inside it is always the same..

```
 var IDData = JSON.stringify([
   [
     "node/105173", 
     "node/38180995", 
     "Agent", 
     "Customer", 
     "1379644.0", 
     1, 
     264.0, 
     "1374903"
   ], [
     "node/1061",
     .........
 ]);
```

Below is my d3.js code to render a force directed graph:

```
 function createNodes (IDData) {

   // is this the right way to make nodes?
   // also how to assign properties to nodes
   var nodes = [{group:1, group: 1}]; 
   var links = [];
   IDData.forEach(function(item){
     nodes.push({id: item, group: 1})
     links.push({source: item, target: item, value: 1}) // missing ;
   });
   var d3GraphData = {
     nodes: nodes,
     links: links
   }
   return d3GraphData;
 };


 function makeGraph (selector, d3GraphData) {
   var svg = d3.select(selector),
   width = +svg.attr("width"),
   height = +svg.attr("height");

   var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);
   var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
     .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }))
     .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
     .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

   var link = svg.append("g")
     .attr("class", "links")
     .selectAll("line")
     .data(d3GraphData.links)
     .enter()
     .append("line")
     .attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

   var node = svg.append("g")
     .attr("class", "nodes")
     .selectAll("circle")
     .data(d3GraphData.nodes)
     .enter()
     .append("circle")
     .attr("r", 5)
     .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
     .call(d3.drag()
       .on("start", dragstarted)
       .on("drag", dragged)
       .on("end", dragended)
     );

   node.append("title")
     .text(function(d) { return d.id; });

   simulation
     .nodes(d3GraphData.nodes)
     .on("tick", ticked);

   simulation.force("link")
     .links(d3GraphData.links);

   function ticked() {
     link
       .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
       .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
       .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
       .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

     node
       .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
       .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
   }

   function dragstarted(d) {
     if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
     d.fx = d.x;
     d.fy = d.y;
   }

   function dragged(d) {
     d.fx = d3.event.x;
     d.fy = d3.event.y;
   }

   function dragended(d) {
     if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
     d.fx = null;
     d.fy = null;
   }

 }

 $(document ).ready(function() {
   console.log(IDData);
   var galData = JSON.parse(IDData);
   var startnodes = [];
   var endnodes = [];
   var nodetype1 = [];
   var nodetype2 = [];
   var PayTime = [];
   var TXN_COUNT = [];
   var Total_Amt = [];
   var SendTime = [];
   ///right way to populate the variables?                
   galData.map(function(e,i){
     startnodes.push(e[0]);
     endnodes.pusg(e[1]);
     nodetype1.push(e[2]);
     nodetype1.push(e[3]);
     PayTime.push(e[4]);
     TXN_COUNT.push(e[5]);
     Total_Amt.push(e[6]);
     SendTime.push(e[7]);
   });

   makeGraph("Network_graph",startnodes,endnodes);

 });
```

var nodetype is a node attribute and var Paytime,TXN_COUNT,Total_Amt,SendTime are link attributes. I need a way to add those vars as text to nodes and links.

Also, when I run this code it fails with:

```
        $not defined Uncaught reference error and  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null
```

and I see this whole dataset as part of the error:

```
  [["node/105173","node/38180995","Agent","Customer","1379644.0",1,264,"1374903"],["node/1061","node/21373542","Agent","Customer","530848.0",1,3000,"529502"],["node/10750","node/59648369","Agent","Customer","1454228.0",1,120,"1454118"],["node/10750","node/78569210","Agent","Customer","1425251.0",1,234,"1421416"],["node/10750","node/96726118","Agent","Customer","1376239.0",1,434,"1376152"],["node/10946829","node/11190","Customer","Agent","1409620.0",20,3380,"1406665"],["node/10946829","node/57774036","Customer","Customer","1460029.0",3,960,"1459731"],["node/109947","node/97911872","Agent","Customer","1323025.0",1,600,"1315582"],["node/11190","node/10946829","Agent","Customer","1552232.0",1,60,"1528755"],["node/11190","node/21373542","Agent","Customer","1445487.0",4,1694,"1432479"],["node/11190","node/21530982","Agent","Customer","1396526.0",4,5428,"1396517"],["node/11190","node/50917084","Agent","Customer","568394.0",1,110,"568380"],["node/11190","node/9837102","Agent","Customer","1485679.0",1,100,"1464486"],["node/113120","node/41382986","Agent","Customer","1327541.0",1,115,"1327526"],["node/11736","node/109816283","Agent","Customer","541087.0",1,300,"504903"],["node/11852","node/84188871","Agent","Customer","1466956.0",1,220,"1465660"],["node/13957774","node/122260","Customer","Agent","1311469.0",1,600,"1309915"],["node/13957774","node/3364","Customer","Agent","1523266.0",1,705,"1523171"],["node/13957774","node/34496","Customer","Agent","1415445.0",1,110,"1413649"],["node/13957774","node/38180995","Customer","Customer","1309063.0",1,981,"1305686"],["node/13957774","node/50706","Customer","Agent","1507302.0",1,100,"1507279"],["node/13957774","node/56357","Customer","Agent","565790.0",1,566,"564113"],["node/13957774","node/57930216","Customer","Customer","1311469.0",3,2205,"1309915"],["node/13957774","node/73290","Customer","Agent","1309063.0",9,3888,"1305686"],["node/13957774","node/74942","Customer","Agent","1364890.0",1,900,"1364667"],["node/13957774","node/79912126","Customer","Customer","577032.0",1,563,"575673"],["node/21042","node/38180995","Agent","Customer","1309063.0",1,981,"1305686"],["node/21373542","node/11190","Customer","Agent","1360573.0",30,14597,"1360504"],["node/21373542","node/26794","Customer","Agent","555473.0",3,729,"554116"],["node/21373542","node/318801","Customer","Agent","578495.0",3,498,"576965"],["node/21373542","node/96726118","Customer","Customer","547027.0",2,620,"546959"],["node/21530982","node/11190","Customer","Agent","1352091.0",9,16089,"1351779"],["node/21530982","node/26794","Customer","Agent","1365616.0",3,855,"1365006"],["node/21530982","node/34971","Customer","Agent","1356124.0",1,232,"1356088"],["node/21530982","node/594","Customer","Agent","1366059.0",1,131,"1365663"],["node/21530982","node/96726118","Customer","Customer","542356.0",1,190,"539601"],["node/21676523","node/1098","Customer","Agent","1455400.0",1,100,"1454479"],["node/21676523","node/11190","Customer","Agent","1313173.0",3,1110,"1308691"],["node/21676523","node/36508","Customer","Agent","1466869.0",2,200,"1465838"],["node/21676523","node/44210","Customer","Agent","1314349.0",2,590,"1313270"],["node/21676523","node/96726118","Customer","Customer","1314517.0",2,190,"1308691"],["node/217106669","node/95506464","ID_Card","Customer","1381993.0",1,241,"1381061"],["node/21767598","node/107904319","Customer","Customer","548231.0",1,70,"547042"],["node/21767598","node/11190","Customer","Agent","1346087.0",2,800,"1345856"],["node/21767598","node/34496","Customer","Agent","1389414.0",6,1720,"1389358"],["node/21767598","node/44210","Customer","Agent","1331714.0",4,1497,"1331581"],["node/21767598","node/57774036","Customer","Customer","1461326.0",1,100,"1460052"],["node/21767598","node/57930216","Customer","Customer","1331714.0",4,1647,"1331581"],["node/21767598","node/78305361","Customer","Customer","1467094.0",2,250,"1467040"],["node/21767598","node/79912126","Customer","Customer","1462602.0",2,1150,"1460055"],["node/21767598","node/97911872","Customer","Customer","1346087.0",2,800,"1345856"],["node/2227","node/50949637","Agent","Customer","542591.0",1,90,"542565"],["node/223142687","node/79912126","ID_Card","Customer","1401002.0",5,3349,"1400955"],["node/233827738","node/38180995","ID_Card","Customer","1309063.0",2,1245,"1305686"],["node/242241128","node/38180995","ID_Card","Customer","534061.0",1,572,"533940"],["node/24598","node/21530982","Agent","Customer","1340319.0",1,967,"1340281"],["node/24598","node/57774036","Agent","Customer","1507220.0",1,400,"1507156"],["node/24598","node/78569210","Agent","Customer","1366161.0",1,1102,"1365085"],["node/24598","node/79912126","Agent","Customer","1401002.0",2,1636,"1400955"],["node/24598","node/97911872","Agent","Customer","1354599.0",1,200,"1354512"],["node/246687492","node/57774036","ID_Card","Customer","1373537.0",14,6078,"1373483"],["node/246822357","node/57930216","ID_Card","Customer","1523266.0",3,2799,"1523171"],["node/26281","node/107904319","Agent","Customer","532576.0",1,200,"528189"],["node/264664319","node/78305361","ID_Card","Customer","1439644.0",4,510,"1439510"],["node/26607156","node/107904319","Customer","Customer","532576.0",1,200,"528189"],["node/26607156","node/109816283","Customer","Customer","541087.0",1,300,"504903"],["node/26607156","node/229153472","Customer","ID_Card","1311457.0",3,4551,"1305670"],["node/26607156","node/34496","Customer","Agent","1311457.0",11,7349,"1305670"],["node/26607156","node/38180995","Customer","Customer","534061.0",1,572,"533940"],["node/26607156","node/44210","Customer","Agent","1381993.0",5,2601,"1381061"],["node/26607156","node/57930216","Customer","Customer","1369110.0",2,2950,"1368981"],["node/26607156","node/78305361","Customer","Customer","1439644.0",2,260,"1439510"],["node/26607156","node/79912126","Customer","Customer","1401002.0",2,1636,"1400955"],["node/26607156","node/84188871","Customer","Customer","1426712.0",2,1571,"1415006"],["node/26607156","node/89031090","Customer","Customer","1429766.0",1,200,"1429513"],["node/26607156","node/94856705","Customer","Customer","1390909.0",1,720,"1390784"],["node/26607156","node/95506464","Customer","Customer","1381993.0",1,241,"1381061"],["node/26607156","node/96726118","Customer","Customer","575821.0",1,100,"575690"],["node/26607156","node/97911872","Customer","Customer","1311457.0",1,1200,"1305670"],["node/26794","node/21530982","Agent","Customer","1366059.0",2,503,"1365617"],["node/269768353","node/84188871","ID_Card","Customer","1426712.0",2,1571,"1415006"],["node/273951326","node/89031090","ID_Card","Customer","1429766.0",1,200,"1429513"],["node/275273379","node/57930216","ID_Card","Customer","1311469.0",14,5014,"1309915"],["node/278851123","node/94856705","ID_Card","Customer","1390909.0",1,720,"1390784"],["node/280383297","node/96726118","ID_Card","Customer","1314517.0",8,1790,"1308691"],["node/281377550","node/97911872","ID_Card","Customer","1311457.0",13,13550,"1305670"],["node/28617767","node/30500","Customer","Agent","1449759.0",1,140,"1446840"],["node/28617767","node/57774036","Customer","Customer","1449759.0",1,140,"1446840"],["node/288503186","node/21767598","ID_Card","Customer","525192.0",1,517,"518059"],["node/289751108","node/107904319","ID_Card","Customer","532576.0",1,200,"528189"],["node/291424813","node/109816283","ID_Card","Customer","541087.0",1,300,"504903"],["node/292764242","node/107904319","ID_Card","Customer","548231.0",1,70,"547042"],["node/30500","node/28617767","Agent","Customer","1442532.0",2,382,"1441513"],["node/30500","node/57930216","Agent","Customer","1331714.0",2,315,"1330439"],["node/30825","node/21676523","Agent","Customer","1347475.0",1,360,"1347336"],["node/318159","node/57774036","Agent","Customer","577148.0",1,231,"577065"],["node/318159","node/96726118","Agent","Customer","547027.0",2,620,"546959"],["node/318801","node/21373542","Agent","Customer","578495.0",3,498,"576965"],["node/32128","node/5864083","Agent","Customer","567267.0",1,146,"566989"],["node/3234768","node/12059","Customer","Agent","1340096.0",4,1600,"1338967"],["node/3234768","node/57774036","Customer","Customer","1537440.0",2,800,"1537296"],["node/3400292","node/2227","Customer","Agent","1413884.0",1,47,"1413760"],["node/3400292","node/47479","Customer","Agent","1331716.0",3,305,"1330439"],["node/3400292","node/57930216","Customer","Customer","1331716.0",4,352,"1330439"],["node/3552445","node/11190","Customer","Agent","1321515.0",22,8729,"1321397"],["node/3552445","node/26794","Customer","Agent","1341655.0",13,2526,"1341558"],["node/3552445","node/44210","Customer","Agent","1325929.0",12,2114,"1325888"],["node/3552445","node/47105","Customer","Agent","1366122.0",1,150,"1366007"],["node/3552445","node/57774036","Customer","Customer","1456987.0",1,300,"1456928"],["node/3552445","node/96726118","Customer","Customer","1376239.0",1,434,"1376152"],["node/36876271","node/54237","Customer","Agent","1373537.0",1,93,"1373483"],["node/36876271","node/57774036","Customer","Customer","1373537.0",1,93,"1373483"],["node/37462520","node/11190","Customer","Agent","1339032.0",3,5250,"1335979"],["node/37462520","node/138138801","Customer","Phone","1798173",1,900,"1795111"],["node/37462520","node/233375474","Customer","ID_Card","1333142.0",5,8250,"1331529"],["node/37462520","node/34496","Customer","Agent","1314404.0",7,6300,"1314302"],["node/37462520","node/97911872","Customer","Customer","1314404.0",10,11550,"1314302"],["node/37498","node/57930216","Agent","Customer","1537660.0",1,94,"1537605"],["node/38180995","node/233827738","Customer","ID_Card","1360339.0",1,240,"1359356"],["node/38180995","node/242241128","Customer","ID_Card","572806.0",1,224,"569839"],["node/38180995","node/40133","Customer","Agent","1360339.0",2,464,"1359356"],["node/38180995","node/59648369","Customer","Customer","1360339.0",1,240,"1359356"],["node/38180995","node/78569210","Customer","Customer","572806.0",1,224,"569839"],["node/3988","node/38180995","Agent","Customer","534061.0",1,572,"533940"],["node/3988","node/57930216","Agent","Customer","1311469.0",12,6993,"1309915"],["node/3988","node/59648369","Agent","Customer","1364760.0",4,901,"1363402"],["node/3988","node/78305361","Agent","Customer","1439644.0",4,510,"1439510"],["node/3988","node/78569210","Agent","Customer","1441112.0",1,140,"1440116"],["node/3988","node/94856705","Agent","Customer","1390909.0",1,720,"1390784"],["node/3988","node/95506464","Agent","Customer","1381993.0",1,241,"1381061"],["node/3988","node/96726118","Agent","Customer","575821.0",2,356,"575690"],["node/3988","node/97911872","Agent","Customer","1311457.0",6,7700,"1305670"],["node/41382986","node/113120","Customer","Agent","1312869.0",3,518,"1311790"],["node/41382986","node/57930216","Customer","Customer","1312869.0",1,303,"1311790"],["node/42799","node/84188871","Agent","Customer","1426712.0",1,1351,"1415006"],["node/44118504","node/21767598","Customer","Customer","525192.0",1,517,"518059"],["node/44118504","node/237596017","Customer","ID_Card","525192.0",1,517,"518059"],["node/44118504","node/725","Customer","Agent","525192.0",1,517,"518059"],["node/44210","node/21676523","Agent","Customer","1313266.0",1,510,"1313177"],["node/44210","node/21767598","Agent","Customer","525192.0",1,517,"518059"],["node/45929","node/107904319","Agent","Customer","548231.0",1,70,"547042"],["node/46619","node/57930216","Agent","Customer","566997.0",1,176,"565619"],["node/49620","node/59648369","Agent","Customer","1351956.0",7,1952,"1351872"],["node/49620","node/78569210","Agent","Customer","1405015.0",4,870,"1404966"],["node/49620","node/89031090","Agent","Customer","1429766.0",1,200,"1429513"],["node/50917084","node/11190","Customer","Agent","568394.0",6,1106,"568376"],["node/50917084","node/96726118","Customer","Customer","578758.0",1,256,"578624"],["node/50949637","node/2227","Customer","Agent","566997.0",6,1432,"565619"],["node/50949637","node/57930216","Customer","Customer","566997.0",3,356,"565619"],["node/52368268","node/2723","Customer","Agent","577148.0",1,231,"577065"],["node/52368268","node/57774036","Customer","Customer","577148.0",1,231,"577065"],["node/54237","node/36876271","Agent","Customer","1421016.0",3,695,"1420930"],["node/5864083","node/119428","Customer","Agent","1419742.0",2,280,"1419720"],["node/5864083","node/20514","Customer","Agent","1577734.0",1,94,"1575388"],["node/5864083","node/21199","Customer","Agent","1563464.0",1,141,"1555202"],["node/5864083","node/32128","Customer","Agent","1310104.0",25,5916,"1309045"],["node/5864083","node/38180995","Customer","Customer","1379644.0",1,264,"1374903"],["node/5864083","node/45202","Customer","Agent","1399277.0",1,237,"1396643"],["node/5864083","node/9238","Customer","Agent","1379644.0",1,264,"1374903"],["node/6643129","node/11190","Customer","Agent","1372272.0",6,2159,"1372134"],["node/6643129","node/26794","Customer","Agent","1576415.0",1,300,"1576375"],["node/6643129","node/44210","Customer","Agent","1369130.0",4,437,"1368964"],["node/6643129","node/57774036","Customer","Customer","1466916.0",1,220,"1465415"],["node/71367","node/28617767","Agent","Customer","1435432.0",1,293,"1433759"],["node/71367","node/57774036","Agent","Customer","1373537.0",12,5447,"1373483"],["node/71367","node/57930216","Agent","Customer","1419567.0",1,235,"1419511"],["node/71367","node/79912126","Agent","Customer","1491585.0",1,900,"1491490"],["node/71367","node/96726118","Agent","Customer","1314517.0",3,380,"1308691"],["node/71367","node/97911872","Agent","Customer","1339029.0",4,4650,"1332931"],["node/8287169","node/12059","Customer","Agent","1554750.0",2,1500,"1553214"],["node/8287169","node/57774036","Customer","Customer","1554750.0",1,1200,"1553214"],["node/84508","node/10946829","Agent","Customer","1576415.0",1,300,"1576375"],["node/92814","node/21530982","Agent","Customer","1321695.0",1,5000,"1321350"],["node/92814","node/79912126","Agent","Customer","1462602.0",2,813,"1460055"],["node/92814","node/97911872","Agent","Customer","1346087.0",1,400,"1345856"],["node/9530944","node/11190","Customer","Agent","1564917.0",1,1800,"1564780"],["node/9530944","node/57774036","Customer","Customer","1564917.0",1,1800,"1564780"],["node/9837102","node/11190","Customer","Agent","1313093.0",14,7931,"1313055"],["node/9837102","node/15987","Customer","Agent","1354658.0",1,150,"1353302"],["node/9837102","node/26794","Customer","Agent","1412451.0",3,520,"1412381"]]
```

I think all the scripts are referenced properly in my HTML. So, I don't know why I'm getting the error.

Comment: $ not defined is a sure sign of jQuery not loading. Check your network/resources tab to be sure that it is loaded.

Comment: @Terry scripts loaded just fine in resources and under network tab both have status of 200 which I guess means "OK"

Comment: Your `<meta charset="UTF-8>` is missing a closing "

Comment: @Mark fixed that. please see the updated question.

Comment: Either jquery is not loaded prior to the code using it attempting to run, or noConflict was called. The other error means that a DOM node is not being found, for example `document.getElementById('non-existing-id')` returns `null`.

Comment: @JaredSmith thanks for the tip. So should i use $.noConflict() between 2 scripts in my HTML.? and I think the other error is related to the createNodes function..I am not specifying a starting point of the node I feel. my startnodes are populated later by  galData.map(function(e,i)

Comment: @mysterious_guy no, you don't need to call noConflict (unless you *do* need to) it just disassociates jquery from the `$`, meaning trying to use `$` would result in an error like the one you're seeing (as would attempting to use jquery before its present on the page). As for the other error, you didn't post any code that calls `getAttribute` so who knows? Psychic we ain't.

Comment: @JaredSmith. Added more code.

Comment: `d3GraphData` is a variable in the `createNodes` function, it is not in scope where you pass it to `.data`.

Comment: `makeGraph` takes two parameters and you pass three.

Comment: @doug65536  Now I can see the nodes but not the links. I was never calling create nodes function. doing that now. And code modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in trying to select the SVG tag "Network_graph". But you can't tell, because you've written you're `makeGraph` function as a black box. I highly recommend restructuring like so:

```
function makeGraph(svg, data) { // pass in the node directly
   // set up d3
}
```

But that's beside the point, the point is that "Network_graph" isn't really a valid css selector. You want to use the css id selector like so:

```
d3.select('#Network_graph');
```

As for the $ not being defined, try replacing with `jQuery` and see if the problem persists.

Comment: So , I added     makeGraph("#Network_graph",startnodes,endnodes); and the Uncaught reference error is gone. But getting a different error. code edited above.

Comment: @mysterious_guy you have now completely altered the question (from being about a JavaScript error to being about using the d3 API), which is considered rude and bad practice. The correct thing to do on stack overflow is accept the answer to the original question, then ask a new one.